# pandas: str.split on both special characters and EOL

Tags: pandas

i have in.csv:

```
Box,Color,Contents
1,Blue,"thing one  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
thing two  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
thing three  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]"
2,Red,thing four  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
3,Green,"thing five  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
thing six  version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]"
```

and i am attempting to create out.csv:

```
Box,Color,Contents
1,Blue,thing one  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
1,Blue,thing two  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
1,Blue,thing three  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
2,Red,thing four  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
3,Green,thing five  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
3,Green,thing six  version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
```

i can use str.split, like so:
`df = pd.DataFrame(df['Contents'].str.split('  ').values.tolist())`

that is just one delimiter.  i need the double-space as well as the end-of-line (EOL), but all my searches on regex say I need to use re.split instead.  My syntax for re isnt working and instead I get:

`df = pd.DataFrame(df['Contents'].re.split('\n' , '  ').values.tolist())`
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 're'`

my search results are spinning out of control.  please assist?
tnx

Comment: Can you show us how you're using regex?

Comment: updated.  tnx...

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you need to use multiple delimiters. You just want to split by "\n" to get separate rows for each "thing" that belongs to the same box, right?

Comment: and in general if you want to use ````re```` on a pandas series, try things like: ````df['Contents'].apply(lambda x: re.split('\n', x))````   You get this error because a pandas series doesn't have a regex module.

Comment: ok, so a couple of things:
i can just focus on the EOL (and perhaps chain another xform later) ... (thanks @xyzjayne)

but now I realize i am creating columns and not rows.  Am i going about this completely wrong?

Comment: You probably want a new dataframe that repeats box and color based on how many "things" you have in "contents".

Comment: thank you again for helping me understand.
so, from here:
https://gist.github.com/jlln/338b4b0b55bd6984f883
near the bottom of the page, JoaoCarabetta offers an updated solution (too long to paste here) that starts with:

    def split_data_frame_list(df, 
                           target_column,
                          output_type=float):

... but I can't figure out how to make it work.  I've tried specifying my df (which, I believe is just df) and I've tried specifying the column as bot Contents and 'Contents'.  These are noob problems, I know... but can you assist?  tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want new rows first (split using `'\r\n'`) and then new columns (split using double space).

This might be a tedious way of doing it, and please let me know if you have anything more Pythonic.

```
df['repeats'] = df['Contents'].str.split('\r\n').apply(lambda x:len(x)) # number of repeats
# create new df
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for i in range(len(df)):
    df1 = df1.append([df.iloc[[i]]]*df.iloc[i]['repeats'])
df1 = df1.reset_index().drop('index',axis = 1)
df1.Contents = sum(df['Contents'].str.split('\r\n').values,[]) #flattening the list
df1[['thing','version','date']] = pd.DataFrame(df1.Contents.str.split('  ').values.tolist())
df1 = df1[['Box','Color','thing','version','date']]
```

Output:

```
  Box  Color        thing      version          date
0   1   Blue    thing one  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
1   1   Blue    thing two  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
2   1   Blue  thing three  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
3   2    Red   thing four  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
4   3  Green   thing five  [version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
5   3  Green    thing six   version 1]  [dd/mm/yyyy]
```

Comment: This is the more Pythonic way I supposed.. https://gist.github.com/jlln/338b4b0b55bd6984f883

Comment: you are correct.  this is exactly what I am trying to do.  let me digest it and see if I can make it fly.  thanks!